# Difference between data sets

Tags: python, math, dataset, numpy, scipy

I have a two data sets as lists, for example:

```
xa = [1, 2, 3, 10, 1383, 0, 12, 9229, 2, 494, 10, 49]    
xb = [1, 1, 4, 12, 1100, 43, 9, 4848, 2, 454, 6, 9]
```

Series are market data that may contain tens of thousands numbers, their length is same.

I need to find "difference" in percents, that shows "how much similarity/dissimilarity between series in percents".
Currently I have an idea to build charts for every list (xa, xb as **Y** ax, and range(1, len(xa)) as **X** ax). interpolate functions for xa, xb, then calculate the area of xa, xb (with integration) and area of difference between xa and xb. After this the dissimilarity is (difference area)*100%/(xa area + xb area).

I wonder if this question has more simple solution.
If not - how can I calculate difference area of xa, xb? Charts are build with scipy, numpy, matplotlib.

**update**: I'm looking for ONE number that represent the difference between sets. Percents are preferred.

Comment: There is no such thing as "magic difference". Do you want correlation coefficient between the two list? What is this difference you're talking about?

Comment: I know it's confused explanation, let it be not limited to correlations. In general when I compare xa and xb, xa and xc, I should know that xa is closer to xc than xa to xb, for example.

Comment: I am thinking that this question might be better asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/ Its not so much a coding question as it is a stats question...

Comment: I don't think it's really high math question that programmers can't answer it, and I need implement it on Python only, so..

Comment: Maybe start with more examples that would show you (and us) what do you treat as similar time series, e.g., how much are [1,2,3,...] and [100,200,300,...] similar? how much are [1,2,3,...] and [0,0,0,1,2,3,...] similar?

Comment: @DominiCane: What you mean by series? How would you describe the 'relation'between xa[i] and xb[i]. Do you expect that some 'relation' of xa[i] and xa[i- 1] is same for xb[i] and xb[i- 1]? I think you'll get more advice on http://stats.stackexchange.com/, sofar the question is not so much related to programming, rather on the question wheter there exist any single number to describe your differences meaninfull way. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you want a similarity metric for comparing two 1D vectors and that preferably returns a value between 0 and 1 (or 0 and 100%), ***cosine similarity*** satisfies those criteria (subject to the proviso at the end). (Whether it's appropriate given the context of your problem, i don't know, but you know the context, so you can certainly make that determination.)

```
import numpy as NP
import numpy.linalg as LA

# generate some data
fnx = lambda : NP.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
s1, s2 = fnx(), fnx()

# a function to calculate cosine similarity
cx = lambda a, b : round(NP.inner(a, b)/(LA.norm(a)*LA.norm(b)), 2)

cx(s1, s2)
# returns 0.85
```

If you have many 1D vectors, then one approach might be to measure the cosine similarity of each of these vectors against the median vector.

In the general case, Cosine similarity returns values between -1 and 1, though in many (most?) practical situations in which it is used, the possible values are constrained between 0 and 1.

Second, the formula for cosine similarity is dot(a, b)/(norm(a) x norm(b)); NumPy has a dot function, however, inner is the NumPy function that implements the dot product.

Comment: I would use rather scipy.signal.pdist(., 'cosine'). LA stands for numpy.linalg, I guess? But seriously what was that in OP's question that makes you to suggest this approach?

Answer (score 3):

This very much depends on the nature of 'similarity' you're seeking.

Two measures spring to my mind.

- Calculate sum of `sqrt((X[i]-Y[i])^2)` or of `abs(X[i]-Y[i])`, normalize to the range of X and Y, that is, from min(X, Y) to max(X, Y). The closer to 0, the more similar are the data sets. The sqrt version is more sensitive to small differences.
- Calculate [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence), it will give you a measure from +1 as 'completely similar' to -1 as 'completely dissimilar'. Note that this 'similarity' *does not* necessarily means that your series follow each other neatly. Take a look at the picture in the wikipedia article.

Comment: completely similar/dissimilar are not good description of correlation results.

Comment: @silenghost: the linked wikipedia article has all the explanations, complete with a picture that shows how limited as a similarity measure correlation is. But the original poster does not specify what is 'similar' in his book, so I also took a bit of, erm, poetic license describing correlation. I'll dampen the wording.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on what you are trying to do. For example, to give a yet given example, you could imagine counting the elements in one but not both sets (length of the symmetric difference of two sets) - if the numbers correspond to measurements, it would be obviously very bad.

You say time series, so can we assume the order matters ?

For time series, it is often beneficial to compute things in the spectral domain, which is something else to consider. Something with a single number is unlikely to give you much information

Answer (score 1):

this what you are looking for?

```
xa = [1, 2, 3, 10, 1383, 0, 12, 9229, 2, 494, 10, 49]    
xb = [1, 1, 4, 12, 1100, 43, 9, 4848, 2, 454, 6, 9]
xc = []

for i in range(0, len(xa)-1):
    xc.append(xa[i] - xb[i])

print xc
```

output:

```
[0, 1, -1, -2, 283, -43, 3, 4381, 0, 40, 4]
```

EDIT:

why not take the percent difference of each value then average them all:

```
from statlib import stats

xa = [1, 2, 3, 10, 1383, 0, 12, 9229, 2, 494, 10, 49]    
xb = [1, 1, 4, 12, 1100, 43, 9, 4848, 2, 454, 6, 9]
xc = []


for i in range(0, len(xa)-1):
    xc.append(abs(float(xa[i] - xb[i])/(xa[i] + xb[i])/2))

print stats.mean(xc)*100
```

if you don't have statlib you can get it [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-statlib/)

Comment: or are you looking for the percent difference of each number?

Comment: I'm looking for ONE magic number, that represents "difference". Percents are preferred. )

Comment: You should at least use abs(xa[i]-xb[i]), otherwise big errors may cancel each other.

Comment: Wondering why I am getting voted down. so that I can at least fix what is wrong with my post...

Comment: @Richard: good, but it wasn't when I made my comment :) I don't think normalizing each point separately makes much sense in your second example, though. Of course, there may be some cases where it would, but generally, you don't want 1 vs 2 to contribute the same as 1000 vs 2000 in a same time series.

Comment: @David Cournapeau: He was asking for "ONE magic number" to represent the difference of both series... you have to normalize or else you would be comparing apples to oranges....

Comment: I don't disagree with normalization per se, but with the normalization factor applied to each time index separately. Concretely, if you had xa = [1, 200, 300] and xb = [2, 200, 300], you would have the same number than in the case xa = [1, 200, 300] and xb = [1, 100, 300] with your normalization scheme.

Comment: @David Cournapeau: fair enough

Comment: @Richard: Even the OP asked 'ONE magic number', IMHO he hasn't explained detailed manner enough of his problem to provide him any code. Secondly at least, because question was tagged also `numpy` and `scipy`, you could provide 'loopless' code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
from itertools import izip, repeat
import math

def weighted_mean(values, weights=None):
    total = 0
    number = 0
    if weights is None:
        weights = repeat(1)
    for weight, value in izip(weights, values):
        total += weight * value
        number += weight
    return number and total / number

xa = [1, 2, 3, 10, 1383, 0, 12, 9229, 2, 494, 10, 49]    
xb = [1, 1, 4, 12, 1100, 43, 9, 4848, 2, 454, 6, 9]


print "Option 1, if you want bigger numbers to have a bigger effect on the score"

weights = (math.sqrt(abs(a) * abs(b)) for a, b in izip(xa, xb))
scores = (abs(a) + abs(b) and abs(a - b) / (abs(a) + abs(b)) for a, b in izip(xa, xb))

final_score = weighted_mean(scores, weights)
print "%.02f%%" % (final_score * 100)


print "Option 2, if you want to have all numbers have the same effect on the score"

scores = (abs(a) + abs(b) and abs(a - b) / (abs(a) + abs(b)) for a, b in izip(xa, xb))

final_score = weighted_mean(scores)
print "%.02f%%" % (final_score * 100)
```

Of course, you can also use other kinds of weights, such as `(abs(a) + abs(b)) / 2`, depending on how you want to interpret a given difference.

Loopless version of the second one:

```
xan = numpy.array(xa)
xbn = numpy.array(xb)
error_threshold = 0.000001
final_score = numpy.mean((abs(xan - xbn) + error_threshold) / (abs(xan) + abs(xbn) + error_threshold))
```

Or the first:

```
scores = (abs(xan - xbn) + error_threshold) / (abs(xan) + abs(xbn) + error_threshold)
weights = numpy.sqrt(abs(xan) * abs(xbn))
final_score = numpy.sum(scores * weights) / numpy.sum(weights)
```

Comment: @ Rosh Oxymoron: What was that in OP's question that makes you to suggest this approach?

Comment: His question? DominiCane wants the difference in percent between two lists of numbers, the mean of the difference between each pair of numbers seems to be a quite possible options, depending on the requirements. Weighted with the arithmetic mean of the two values, it will yield exactly the area difference suggested in the OP which is good if an exact quantity difference is expected, unweighted it will yield something good for input that's not normalized or the change is expected to be proportional to the value (average salary in different countries), etc.